# Git Diff or Merge completely lost between 2 branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

We are new to git, (we came from perforce) and we use git for 2-3 mount now. Today we are facing a strange conflict merge on one file. Git and our MergeTool (P4Merge) lost completely the change on the file and detect 183 changes or conflicts!
So let start with some image. We got 2 branches, DEV and FT/MEP. Dev got several change so we decide to merge changes from DEV to FT/MEP before continuing work on FT/MEP code. After the merge, we got one file with conflicts but after opening in our merge tool all the change/conflict on the file was very strange.

So I do a diff between the old merge and the last commit on the conflict file for the DEV branch (Green line)
[image]

Only one function was added on that file:
[image]

I do the same thing on the FT/MEP branch (yellow line), only one function is added to in that branche.
[image]

So normally after the merge, in the conflict resolution  I will have one function to add from REMOTE and one another function to add from LOCAL et the MERGED file.
But the merge tool found several change, function name add or remove bur we never touch these function and they are present both side!
Just for test I ask git for diff between the 2 head of each branch (just before mergin):
[image]

He we got this:

[image]
[image]

Everything is mixed up!
I don’t understand we and how to resolve this?

We use Sourcetree with Git ver 2.27.0 and P4Merge

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are diffing the wrong things and perhaps misinterpreting your own results.

How does a merge work? It starts at the newest *common* commit, the *merge base*, which in this case is your "dev: permissions Alain Carpentier". It diffs that against the final commits of *both* branches, and replays *both* those diffs simultaneously against the merge base. I think you'll find that if you look at those diffs, what's happening will make sense.

Keep in mind that git knows nothing about "only one function". It just goes line by line as best it can. If there's an added line in one file but not the other, it inserts it. If there's a removed line in one file but not the other, it removes it. But if there's an added line in *both* files and they *differ*, git doesn't know how to proceed; that's the "conflict".

So what's happening here is that it works its way down the file in that manner, comes to line 9904, and comes to those two functions simultaneously. So now, as your diff-tool shows, if we go line by line, there are lines that are one way in one file and the other way in the other file. Those are the conflicts.